# How to change the color of a row using its id in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am breaking my head to do something very simple with Jquery and CSS but I am in a dead end.

I make an ajax request in which I update a PostgreSQL table and return some id.
The returning id is the same with the id of the row of a table I have defined previously:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var ajaxurl = 'requestsII/updateStatus.php'; // script to run
    data =  {datastr:tr_id,datastr1:komvosName,datastr2:current_selection}; 
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        var response = JSON.parse(response); 
        console.log(response);                              
        var id = response[0]['itemcode'];                                                    $("'#"+id+"'").css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
     });
 });
```

What I am trying to do is to change the color of the row with the id equal to:

```
   var id = response[0]['itemcode'];
```

I have tried different ways but it seems I am doing something wrong.

Comment: post your html and css too

Comment: @RamanathanMuthuraman why is there any need for css posted? That has no relevance to the situation

Comment: will have to check whether the style was applied to tr/td and what was the styling statement that was used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `css`:

```
$('#' + response[0]['itemcode']).css('background-color', 'green');
```

The highlighted things are not needed.

```
$("'#"+id+"'").css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
// ^     ^^^^

$("#" + id).css({backgroundColor: 'red'}); // Corrected
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#' + id).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

However, I would recommend you to use[`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

> Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
<style>.YourCSSClass{background-color : red } </style>
```

*Script*

```
$('#' + id).addClass('YourCSSClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

simple:-

```
$('#' + response[0]['itemcode']).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

this will be work

$('#'+id).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});

try it